# onmouseover text is displayed everytime you open the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a project, where a **Text** should be **displayed** If I **hover** over a picture.
It works fine for displaying and not displaying part, but the problem I'm having right now, is that if I start the Page it is displayed. If I hover over it and out of it it works again. It stays invisible from then on but at the start it is displayed.

So, If I start the homepage, it should be invisible until I hover over it.

For the JS part I used `.style.visiblity= "visible"; and "hidden";`

for the HTML part I used a new `<div>` for the text itself with: `style="visibility:none;"`

```
<div class="responsive">
    <div id="picture1" class="img" >
        <img src="../picture1" alt="picture1" width="600" height="400"  onmouseover="funcOver('picturetext')" onmouseout="funcOut('picturetext')">
        <div class="desc" style="font-family: Luminari;">HOLIDAY</div>
        <div id="picturetext" style="visibility:none;"> This is a photo<br>
        of our holiday. </div> 
    </div>  
</div>
```

JS:

```
function funcOver(x)
    {
        document.getElementById(x).style.visibility = "visible";


    }

function funcOut(x){

    document.getElementById(x).style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Comment: Please share your code or replicate the issue in a snippet or a fiddle.

Comment: I'd recommend 'display' with 'none' and 'initial' as values instead of 'visibility'.

Comment: Change style="visibility:none; to style="visibility:hidden;" in your HTML (inline CSS)... and it will work.  https://jsfiddle.net/dzzwtpra/1/ Possible values for visibility property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility

Comment: changing it from none to hidden fixxed the problem! Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like a css only problem to me. No need for any script.

Comment: Yeah, but we are learning JS so we need to use it :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use OnLoad property on the element?

[OnLoad event - W3CSchools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)

Or CSS Display:

[CSS Display visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)